# Can't read/write on Hard Disk

Tags: hard-drive

I recently installed two hard disks into my system, I formatted them as ext4, but I can't read/write them!

The properties show that the owner is "root".

I named the hard disks "Hard Disk 1" and "Hard Disk 2".

How can I change the ownership to my user (daniel), so I can edit/create/delete/read files?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a permissions problem unless the drive is very old which have been know to cause intermittent permissions problems. Check out [this document](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions) from Ubuntu to learn about this kind of errors.